# For using ThreadSafeReference, how to compose Result from array of object

Tags: swift, multithreading, realm

Below is the db model design;

```
class Routing: Object {

    dynamic var channelCode: String = ""
    dynamic var storeCode: String = ""
    dynamic var userId = 0


    dynamic var startDate: Date = Date()
    dynamic var endDate: Date = Date()  
}
// primary keys:  channelCode + storeCode + userId + startDate + endDate

class StoreDB: Object {
    dynamic var storeCode: String = ""
    dynamic var channelCode: String = ""

    dynamic var areaCode: String = ""  
}
// primary keys: storeCode + channelCode
|
```

For example:

```
Routing(channelCode: "Waston", storeCode: "AL", userId = 18, startDate 
 = "2017-01-01", endDate = "2018-01-01")
Routing(channelCode: "Manning", storeCode: "AL", userId = 18, startDate 
 = "2017-07-01", endDate = "2018-01-01")

StoreDB(storeCode: "AL", channelCode = "Waston", areaCode = "hk")
StoreDB(storeCode: "AL", channelCode = "Manning", areaCode = "hk")
```

Will using userId to query `Routing` table, get `Result<Routing>`; then

```
Result<Routing>.forEach({  routing in
    let channelCode = routing.channelCode
    let storeCode = routing.storeCode
    // using channelCode, storeCode to query Store
})
```

then get

```
Result<Routing>.forEach({  routing in
        Result<Store>
})
```

my final goal is get `Result<Store>`, then could use `ThreadSafeReference(to: Result<Store>)` for passing `Result<Store>` to main thread

But here Result can not using append function, and could not convert `Array` to `Result`. So how could i solve this problem, when i have to pass Result to main thread?

Comment: You cannot create `Results` or `List` instances manually, so you cannot convert an array to `Results`. You most probably need to change your data models and use Realm relationships to "link" `Routing` and `StoreDB` instances. Please explain the connection between `Routing` and `StoreDB` to understand whether you need to have a one-to-one, one-to-many or inverse relationship between your models.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Added the primary keys for 2 tables in the question, thanks

Comment: That doesn't really help, since it doesn't tell anything about the relationship between a `Routing` object and the `Store` object(s) it relates to. A single `Store` object is linked to a single `Routing` object based on the compound primary key of `channelCode` + `storeCode`?

Comment: Update the question with example;  Actually a single ```Routing``` with ```channelCode``` ```storeCode```, could link to a single ```Store```